# Reading a file from Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I am looking for advice in structure rather than particular coding.
My program has a Main class that initializes a GUI and then, after puting the name of the files that are going to be read, I click one button. I attached a listener with the respective mouseClicked event handler and I do all my routines INSIDE the handler.

This doesn't seem a good approach, is it? Is it usual to do things this way? All my program inside an event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This doesn't seem a good approach, is it? Is it usual to do things this way? All my program inside an event handler?

You are right, this isn't a good approach. Instead look into implementing a Model-View-Control (MVC) type structure or one of its variants.

- The Model: this is the brains of your program, the one that holds the program state. This should contain no GUI code, no listener code, just the data and the logic that goes with the data. The model should not implement a handler interface
- The View: this is the GUI, here your Swing components and related code. The view should not implement a handler interface.
- The Control: this is the connecting code between the two above, the code that handles user interactions, asks the model to change state. This *may* implement a handler interface, or have inner classes that do, or be composed of objects that do. Your control for instance could read in the file (in a background thread), supply the text to the model, and then the model could notify the view (or the control -- there are many variants of this) that its state has changed.
- As an aside: don't give a JButton a MouseListener. Use an ActionListener instead.

Comment: I've read about MVC and I think that is the way to go, for people like me that found this thread looking for help, look here for a simple example of MVC: http://shulgadim.blogspot.pt/2012/01/model-view-controller-mvc-pattern_13.html.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it usual to do things this way?

UI programming is [event-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) in Swing. Twisting it into any other style will not make it easier for you. What you might mean is that you should minimize the code in that UI part.

This means that you shouldn't tie the UI to the logic, therefore creating dense coupling. In this example, the file-reading code should be moved into another method, ideally in another class.

> All my program inside an event handler?

To answer this specific question: No, that'd be terrible! It's okay to invoke your program from there, but don't write the code in the event-handler!

Comment: But if I call there a method of another class that calls many other methods that call many other methods isn't that the same? I agree that one should take advantage of methods to organize the code better, but if I just rely on calling methods the code is all going to execute in the handler, only organized in methods (I feel like I am repeating myself, sorry).

Comment: @rmarques: It's not `going to execute in the handler`. There are several aspects about, thread-wise and code-organization-wise. Thread-wise, you should not do long and blocking operations on the UI thread, the handler. Code-organization-wise, it's okay to invoke it from the handler.

Comment: @StackverFlowException: Maybe I misunderstood what "invoke" means. Isn't that calling methods? If I call a method inside the handler that makes a delay of 1 second, is the GUI going to stop working for 1 second? I think that was my initial question in other words :)

Comment: @rmarques: it will freeze the GUI if you call it on the Swing event thread. For that reason, any code that takes longer than a split second to run should be run in a background thread. 1+ to this excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **rules** but only **good practices**.
And from Good Practice ethics, it is always advised to divide your code into small chunks, each one responsible for some stuff.

So you would better move your code outside the event handler and delegate the job to some method called `readFiles()` and call the later within your handler.

And even if this method can be cut into pieces you can do the same, e.g. it can only iterate over the files to be read and call a `readFile()` method for each one:

```
private void readFiles(Files[] files)
{
  for(File file : files)
  {
    readFile(file);
  }
}
```

***Just a simple snippet and all should be updated to follow your model.***

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly instead of providing a path to the file you can use
  `JFileChooser` to do file selection operations. Especially since you
  are using `Swing`.
- Secondly one should attempt to modularize the code to an extent it
  makes code looks simpler a d understandable. So you can create a
  separate method that handles your file operations. The you can call
  this function from any event handler. Be it mouse or keyboard. This
  will avoid code duplication and will enable module reude.